# convert arraylist of objects to parcel and back

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

i have the following class:

```
public class Ad extends ListItem implements Parcelable {


private String _type;
    private String _recordID; 
    private String _line1;
    private String _line2;
    private String _line3;
    private String _line4;
    private String _url;
    private Double _longitude;
    private Double _latitude;


public Ad() {

    }

    public Ad(Parcel parceledAd) {

        set_url(parceledAd.readString());
        set_latitude(parceledAd.readDouble());
        set_longitude(parceledAd.readDouble());
        set_recordID(parceledAd.readString());
        set_line1(parceledAd.readString());
        set_line2(parceledAd.readString());
        set_line3(parceledAd.readString());
        set_line4(parceledAd.readString());
    }

// getters and setters for appropiate fields are skipped but they exsist.

<pre>// inherited from listItem
    @Override
    public ListItemType getType() {
        return ListItemType.Ad;
    }
    <pre>// inherited from the parcelable interface</pre>

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parceledAd, int flags) {

        parceledAd.writeString(get_url());
        parceledAd.writeDouble(get_latitude());
        parceledAd.writeDouble(get_longitude());
        parceledAd.writeString(get_recordID());
        parceledAd.writeString(get_line1());
        parceledAd.writeString(get_line2());
        parceledAd.writeString(get_line3());
        parceledAd.writeString(get_line4());

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Ad> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Ad>() {

        @Override
        public Ad createFromParcel(Parcel parceledAd) {
            return new Ad(parceledAd);
        }

        @Override
        public Ad[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Ad[size];
        }

    };

}
```

on the source activity i have an array list of type :-

`private ArrayList<ListItem> _items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();`

which contains a list of `ad` objects ( which is a child of `ListItem` that contains only an `enum`.

i want to create an array list of a parceled `Ad` objects from `_items ArrayList<ListItem>`

the parcelised implementation was performed on the Ad class.

i would appreciate some examples on how to achieve that.

I have tried using the methods described in the developer site:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,MapActivity.class);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ads", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) _items);
```

in the source activity and

_items=intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("ads");

in the destination activity but i get an error :

Bound mismatch: The generic method getParcelableArrayListExtra(String) of type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String). The inferred type ListItem is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

please help

Comment: what have you tried ? this should be pretty straighforward from the android examples

Comment: ArrayList itself is Serializable..

Comment: i have tried using the developer guide example:

Answer (score 0):

On your code, `Ad` class implements `Parcelable`, not `ListItem`, make `ListItem` implement `Parcelable` and then your code should work.